# SQL JOIN Requests in Django using for loops, is there a better approach?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a Web App similar to a Web E-commerce site where various persons from different companies can enter their products in the admin page of my web app.
I am trying to get each user to view  in the Admin page, only the products of the company he belongs, in more detail the products that belong to a company with VAT the same as the user's company vat.

My models schema is sth like. Product with a Foreign Key to Line of Products, which has a Foreign Key to Catalogue, which finally has a Foreign Key to Company. So in order to achieve the above I came up with sth like the code below:

---

```
**admin.py**
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    else:
        try:
            comp = Company.objects.get(vat_number = request.user.get_profile().organization_vat)
            comp_catalogs = Catalog.objects.filter(company_id = comp.id)
            print '3. ', comp_catalogs
            lista = []
            for cat in comp_catalogs:
                lista.append(cat.id)
            print '4. ', lista
            lines = Line.objects.filter(catalog_id__in=lista)
            lista = []
            for line in lines:
                lista.append(line.id)
            return qs.filter(line_id__in=lista)
        except:
            return qs.none()
```

---

Is there a way to make the above series of queries in a nicer way (less code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    else:
        return qs.filter(line__catalog__company__vat_number=request.user.get_profile().organization_vat)
```

Comment: 15 lines transformed to 1. Really nice one!!!. Thanks ziima thanks StackOverFlow.